# MVC access multidimensional array on view and display values

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

In my ajax function success part when I alert data , I can see data as `two dimensional array` but when I try to display `$jobs` data on view  i am not getting $jobs array ,why is that so , I also tried to send JSON format of array to access it but it didn't work .where is mistake ?

**getting array as**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [jsp_title] => php developer job
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [jsp_title] => java developer job
        )
)
```

**controller**

```
public function processjobsearch()
    { //print_r($_POST);
    try {       
            $valToSearch = isset($_POST['keyword']) ? trim($_POST['keyword']) : NULL;
            $datepicker = isset($_POST['datepicker']) ? trim($_POST['datepicker']) : NULL;
            $jobdate = strtotime($datepicker);
            $nature = isset($_POST['nature']) ? trim($_POST['nature']) : NULL;
            $location = isset($_POST['location']) ? trim($_POST['location']) : NULL;
           $jobs = $this->_model->getJobSearchData($valToSearch, $nature, $location, $jobdate);    
         //return  json_encode($jobs);
           $this->_view->set('jobs', $jobs);    
           return $this->_view->output();

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo '<h1>Application error:</h1>' . $e->getMessage();
        }       
    }
```

**view**

```
<script>
        function jobsearch()
        {
             var form=$("#jobSearchForm")   
               //$("#result").html("<img alt="ajax search" src='ajax-loader.gif'/>"); 
             $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/jobs/processjobsearch/',
                    data: form.serialize(),
                    success: function(data){
                         //alert(data);                  
                        $("#keyword").val("");              
                        }       
                }); 
        }
</script>
    <table border='solid'>
    <tr><th>Title</th><th>Description</th></tr>
    <?php print_r($jobs); ?>
    <?php  if ($jobs):
       foreach ($jobs as $row => $value): ?>
    <tr><td><?php echo $value['jsp_title']; ?></td><td><?php echo $value['jsp_desc']; ?></td></tr>
    <?php 
                                                                endforeach;
                                                                else: ?>

                                                                    <?php endif; ?>
    </table>
```

**model**

```
public function getJobSearchData($valToSearch, $nature, $location, $jobdate)
     { 
     $sql = "SELECT
                     *
                    FROM
                     js_projects
                     WHERE ";

         if($valToSearch || $nature || $location || $jobdate)
       {
        $sql .= "jsp_title like '%$valToSearch%' OR jsp_nature like '%$nature%' OR jsp_location like '%$location%' OR jsp_date like '%$jobdate%' ";
       }    
         //echo $sql;                               
             $this->_setSql($sql);                
             $jobs = $this->getAll();
        print_r($jobs);
        if (empty($jobs))
            { 
                return false;
            }       
        return $jobs;
     }
```

Comment: can you show your view part `html code` where you want to append this array?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh I have edited view part

Comment: Please check my answer. you need to change your view code completely like that.thanks